# Compiling py file to pyc causing program to fail

Tags: python

I have made some changes to an existing python program. I have tried to compile the `py` file using both

`python -m py_compile maina.py` in the terminal

and

```
import py_compile
py_compile.compile("maina.py")
```

It works but results in a file called `maina.cpython-37` and the program doesn't run.

The changes to the script are minor and shouldn't be the cause of the program not running.

I am new to python and have not been able to find an answer to find out what the problem is. Can anyone help?

Comment: You know that python is an interpreted language? So there are scripts (*.py) and modules (*.py, *.pyc) both formats are not machine specific and must be interpreted by an interpreter (or virtual machine). Short version you don't need to compile a program to run it.

Comment: If you run your program using `python maina.py`, what happens?

Comment: How do you execute the compiled file?

Comment: Hi Wolf, thanks. The programme comprises lots of different scripts/modules (it's a scraper using scrapy) so running just maina does not do anything.

Comment: Hi MisterMiyagi, there's a batch file